# How to make generator throw upon creation instead of during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following code:

```
def gen():
    raise ValueError("foo")
    yield from range(10)

g = gen() # does not raise

for i in g:
    print(i) # raises "foo"
```

How do I make the generator throw during the initial call? I know generators are lazily evaluated, but one use for this is to check the validity of arguments into the generator.

I'm using python 3.6.5.

Comment: could you add an example (code, if possible) about what you mean? You could use a wrapper function that itself checks the validity of the arguments

Comment: Does the generator have any side effects or would `itertools.tee` + nexting the copied generator work?

Comment: You can just return from a generator. `def gen(early_stop=False):`, `if early_stop: return`, which would lead to `g = gen(early_stop=True)`.

Comment: `tee` itself doesn't try to iterate over its argument immediately. Having two iterators means caching every value produced by one of them until the second one produces it as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a regular function that calls the generator function only after the arguments are verified.

```
def make_gen(x):
    if not_good(x):
        raise ValueError("foo")
    def gen():
        yield from range(x)
    return gen()
```

`gen` doesn't have to be nested, to avoid having to redefine that function every time `make_gen` is called.

```
def make_gen(x):
    if not_good(x):
        raise ValueError("foo")

    return gen()


def gen(x):
    yield from range(x)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of verifying arguments if `gen()` is "public" (i.e., `make_gen` can be circumvented)? Could you not just `return (yield from range(10))` from `make_gen()`?

Comment: Nvm that doesn't seem to work. Not sure why.

Comment: `yield` can only be used in a function definition. You could write `return iter(range(10))` in this specific instance.